# According to parameter different report should open on Image(button) click in ssrs 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I am working on SSRS 2005 and creating report, The report has two parameter one is **date** and other is **Department**. Department parameter may be null.There is also image(button) **Graphical View**.

Now condition is....

1. When I pass only date and click on the button then
   **"AllDepartmentReport"** Should open.
2. When I pass date and department then only **"DepartmentWiseReport"** should open.

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression for the action of your image.

Something like:

```
=IIF(
    ISNOTHING(Parameters!Department.Value), 
    "AllDepartmentReport", 
    "DepartmentWiseReport"
)
```